# Python does not read unicode U + FE0F

Tags: python, whatsapp, emoji

Suppose I export a WhatsApp chat as .txt and then read it with python. It seems that python does not read the right unicode combinations for emoji containing \uFE0F. For example the rainbow flag emojis ️‍ is U+1F3F3 U+FE0F U+200D U+1F308. However, if i read the file with python, using the code below, the flag emoji is read as \U0001f3f3\u200d\U0001f308. Is there a problem with my code? Is the file exported by WhatsApp incorrect? Or is there some other reason that this behaves likes this?

I want to write a program that finds all emoji in a chat, however \U0001f3f3\u200d\U0001f308 is not an existing emoji, so I get an error now...

```
def showchat():
    f = open("MyChat.txt", "r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        print(l)
        print(str(l.encode('unicode-escape')))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Which version of Python? You're not setting a codec for the file.

Comment: @Mark Ransom 3.6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that WhatsApp exports their files in UTF-8 format. So you must set that encoding when you [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the file:

```
f = open("MyChat.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

It's possible that your Python installation already defaults to UTF-8, since you didn't get an error when your program attempted to read the file. Since [`'\ufe0f'`](https://codepoints.net/U+FE0F?lang=en) is a special Unicode codepoint that doesn't represent an actual character, it may not be exported properly by WhatsApp.  You would need to do a hex dump of the file to determine what it actually contains.

Comment: My Python installation indeed defaults to utf-8, so I guess the problem is with the file exported by whatsapp. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but worth explaining what is going on. The issue is not Python. It may not even be Whatsapp, it could be the keyboard software the user used to type the emoji.

---

There are two ways for the rainbow flag to be written. Looking at the `emoji-test.txt` file from Unicode (found [here](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/emoji-test.txt)):

```
1F3F3 FE0F 200D 1F308                                  ; fully-qualified     # ️‍ E4.0 rainbow flag
1F3F3 200D 1F308                                       ; unqualified         # ‍ E4.0 rainbow flag
```

The first way is the one you expected, and the second way is the one Whatsapp is generating. The first way is fully-qualified, while the second is unqualified. You can find definitions of those terms [here](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#def_qualified_emoji_character), but basically fully-qualified means that all the recommended code points are included. In this case that means that `FE0F` is there, which explicitly tells renderers that this emoji should be displayed graphically, not in a text format like ☺.

The unqualified format is not really supposed to appear, keyboards are never supposed to generate them. But pretty much all renderers, like your browser, fonts, Whatsapp, will render them as emojis because it helps keep things working and looking nice in case they unqualified emojis do appear.

In general, software parsing unknown input like yours should support all three  variants of emoji (fully-, minimally-, and unqualified), so you should change your code to recognize both these rainbow flag emojis as valid.

For more info, you can look at the Unicode [Emoji Implementation Notes](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Implementation_Notes), as well as my previous link. You'll also want to know about [Zero Width Joiners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) if you don't already.